# php - refactoring a class with object composition

Tags: php, class, refactoring

I recently had some time to refactor an old personal project and i wanted to use it as a learning experience on how to best deal with this kind of class.

The problem is my class (item) has 2 genders associated with it (and in the future may have more like a poster of the item, and hats/accessories of the item), each of these genders uses nearly identical methods to get and set things about them (get_productImage, set_price, etc).

I wanted to refactor the class so that instead of using a male and female counterpart for each function, i could have the code written once, and use it twice (or more). Here is (a very simplified example of) what i have so far:

```
class Item
{
    public $ID, $displayDate;
    public $male, $female;

    public function __construct($ID)
    {
        //Fancy code to initialize stuff like $displayDate
        $male = new Gender('male', $ID, $displayDate);
        $female = new Gender('female', $ID, $displayDate);
    }
}

class Gender
{
    private $ID, $displayDate;

    public function get_currentPrice()
    {
        //The current price of the gender changes based on the display date vs the current date and then adjusts the price accordingly and returns it.
    }
}
```

Is there a way that i can re-write this better? The other problem i have is that the displayDate can (and will be) changed and shuffled around a lot so any changes to it need to be propagated to the gender class as well which is going to make this a huge mess...

If it helps, i am using php 5.4 so any new things added to that can be used here as well.

Comment: Can you not use Inheritance

Comment: @Dave the reason i don't want to go with inheritance is that i really want one class that will encapsulate the different types of items. most of the stuff in the item is the same, and will get changed semi-frequently, so i would rather change it in one place than have to change it in both extended classes.

Comment: how about creating a container class that stores instances of the sub objects and their relationships. so you'd have class $useritems which owns which $items and which $gender are selected and associated.  Or perhaps you could just use a list to hold the relationships?

Comment: I understood it right? Item is a shirt, and one shirt exists as male and female model? What if a model for childs exists, too for example? You'd better have a property `$type`. Than make different instances for different types.

Comment: @redreggae passing a `$type` each time i need to access something gender specific was my fallback plan, i was just hoping there was a more 'elegant' solution to this problem. (like i said, this is more of a learning experience than actual work)

Comment: factory pattern for creation of an item containing the item + options etc ?

Comment: I think you are very limited with this kind of design. In case of doubt always think of the real world objects: One shirt = One instance of item. Then you have different attributes: id, color, gender (or type) etc.

Comment: Yeah, the way this entire system was written, it treats an 'item' class as a specific thing which has different parts (male, female, etc). The reason i wanted to refactor it to OOP was to make everything easier (rather than change the male's date, then the female's date, i just change one date and it's done)

Answer (score 1):

I see two general ways of solution.

One is that you glue both genders on single class and distinguish between male/female with some kind of flag (for example, 'type' of you plan to have more than two genders).

Another is using traits.

For example, you know that $displayDate is always being get/set and treated the same way. So you make a trait, say, hasDisplayDate, where you specify property (protected $displayDate) and all the necessary methods. And in genders you just add 'use hasDisplayDate' to admix the trait. You can overload methods that are present in traits when you need.

Comment: Interesting I never knew php had traits.  Going to upvote you for that.

Comment: Can you expand on how traits can be used here? I read a little bit about them but i am having trouble understanding how they apply to this situation.

Comment: I've added a gist with short example: [link](https://gist.github.com/ozgg/5467319)

Comment: ah, thats not exactly what i was looking for, but it does actually help understand how traits work a bit more.